# How to distort just a specific frequency range using javascript web audio?

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I have a small web app that models deafness based on a person's individual audiogram (http://howdeaf.com).  Essentially, it goes:

`source -> 2-ch splitter -> 6 inline frequency separators -> merge node -> destination
                         -> 6 inline frequency separators ->`

The frequency separators are created using this code:

```
for (let i = 0; i < bandSplit.length; i++) {
    for (let j in sides) {
        var side = sides[j];
        let filterNode = context.createBiquadFilter();
        filterNode.frequency.value = bandSplit[i];
        if (i === 0)
            filterNode.type = 'lowshelf';
        else if (i === bandSplit.length - 1)
            filterNode.type = 'highshelf';
        else
            filterNode.type = 'peaking';
        filterNode.gain.value = 0.0;

        this.eqNodes[side].push(filterNode);

        if (i > 0)
            this.eqNodes[side][i - 1].connect(this.eqNodes[side][i]);
    }
}
```

I adjust the gain on each of the 12 frequency separator nodes, and it's a pretty neat simulation.

I'd like to add distortion (using `createWaveShaper()`), individually, using different curve values, to each of those 12 biquad filter nodes, but I've not had any success distorting just the individual frequency.  Any distortion node I create affects the entire audio output for that channel.

Is there any way to apply distortion to those frequency-selection nodes on an individual basis?

Comment: Where did you put the WaveShaper nodes?

Comment: @RaymondToy I tried connecting a WaveShaper to each of the biquad nodes, but that was obviously wrong; it shaped all sounds passing through and not just the frequency targetted by the biquad filter. I then rearranged them in parallel instead of series, source -> splitter -> [biquad -> wave shaper] -> merger -> destination (12 of [those], 6 for each channel) but that didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

All but two of your filters are peaking filters with a gain of 0.  That basically lets everything through.  So whatever wave shaping you apply gets applied to the whole frequency band.  (See, for example,  http://googlechrome.github.io/web-audio-samples/samples/audio/mag-phase.html to get graphs of the responses.)

Consider using different kinds of filters such as bandpass filters. This might not be appropriate for you application, but at least these filters don't let all frequencies through.

Comment: I'm not an audio engineer by any means, so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.  At first, I wanted to adjust the gain on each frequency range independently. My setup achieved that, but maybe it's ham-fisted. Do you have a cleaner approach?  Second goal would be to add distortion to each of those frequency ranges, again, independently. Would a parallel set of bandpass filters allow this?

Comment: Yes, a parallel set of bandpass filters will allow this, up to a point.  You'll have to choose the bandwidths and center frequencies carefully so that result is basically flat. Not sure how easy that is.  Then you can apply the distortion on each output.  However, the filters aren't perfect so there will be some overlap in frequencies so some distortion will spill over into other bands.

Comment: I read up on "Q values" and looked at a couple graphs, so I think I see what you mean by "overlap" and I think it'll be minimal and acceptable (if those graphs are accurate, and my Qs are done right).  I'll test it out and post the result code if it works.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Please do. I'd like to see how it goes since I've never done that.